# Why is this function returning all True values?

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop, if-statement, printing

I am defining a function that takes the sum of each list and checks to see whether the individual sum of each list is even. If it is even, I would like to return True. Otherwise, I would like to return False

I want it to iterate through the sum of each list, but it looks like right now the loop is just checking the first list and stopping.

Also, is there any way to display the answer by not including the print statement? I feel like I have done that in the past, but it does not seem to be working for me this time around.

Comment: You're returning after you check the first list. In your examples, all of the first lists have even sums (4, 6 and 6).

Comment: Ahh. Is there any way to check all the lists? Thanks by the way

Comment: Move the return true outside of the for loop. That way when you get to the end of the function, if you haven't returned, that means all the rows are true, so you can return true.

Comment: That turns it into None, None and False. Do you know what I am doing wrong this time?

Comment: Sounds like you didnt move the `return true`, you removed it. You still need the `return true` at the end of your function. Amit's answer is what I was trying to get across :).

Answer (score 1):

It's checking the first row because you are returning from the function as soon as the first list in a bigger list is checked. If you want to return for each of the lists in your bigger list. Then you should store the True and False values in a new list and return that list.  Here's the new version of your code that you should write -

```
def evenrow(intList):
    result = []
    for i in intList:
        if sum(i)%2==1:
            result.append(False)
        else:
            result.append(True)

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

The first item in list of lists sums up to an even number. Thus in your function, once that is satisfied,  the function exits with True value. Remaining items will not be checked.
If you want to check whether all items sum to even then, you will have to slightly modify the code.

```py
def evenrow(intList):
    AllEven = True
    for i in intList:
        if sum(i)%2==1:
            AllEven = False
    return AllEven
```

I am sorry if I misread the requirement.